# Search Entries for HTML Code

Tags: admin

I'm trying to use the Admin interface to search entries with specific types of HTML code entered incorrectly by a client. What is the best way to do this?

Searching for the html itself "<span" doesn't not yield correct results. The field with this text in is it search indexed.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Craft’s [search system](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/searching.html) indexes and matches against normalized keywords, not exact text. HTML in particular has all its special characters stripped out, so something like `<span class="busted>markup</span>` would end up being indexed as `span class busted markup span`! Your search query is *also* normalized, though, so a query for `<span` *should* match at least the `span` keyword…

If you know which fields contain the bad code, you can use the condition builder to query against actual field data. Alternatively, building the query in a template will give you precise control over the input:

```
{% set badEntries = craft.entries()
  .myFieldWithPotentiallyMalformedHtml('*<span*')
  .all() %}
```

This will return an entry that has `<span class="busted>markup</span>` in it.

---

Keep in mind that this is only doing simple string matching in the database—if you need to scan for in/valid HTML or specific HTML attributes, you may need to perform more advanced matching with PHP… perhaps by loading *all* potentially-affected entries, then scanning the field values with regular expressions, HTMLPurifier, or other techniques!

Comment: Thank you so much!